# Gerar Assinatura Pagseguro API

Tags: php, xml

Bom, preciso gerar assinatura via API do pagseguro, usuário deverá ser redirecionado para a página do pagseguro e ao finalizar retornar para minha página, isso deve ser via API.

Tentei através do XML, com os códigos:

```
$url = "https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/pre-approvals/request?email=meuemail@hotmail.com&token=********************************";

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="charset=ISO-8859-1"?>
<preApprovalRequest>
    <reviewURL>http://www.site.com.br/dashboard/revisao.php</reviewURL>
    <redirectURL>http://www.site.com.br/painel/sucesso.php</redirectURL>
    <reference>EVX01</reference>
    <sender>
        <name>Jose de Solza</name>
        <email>leonidaswander@gmail.com</email>
       <phone>
         <areaCode>11</areaCode>
         <number>56273440</number>
       </phone>
       <address>
       <street>Avenida Brigadeiro Faria Lima</street>
         <number>1384</number>
         <complement>1 Andar</complement>
         <district>Jardim Paulistano</district>
         <postalCode>01452002</postalCode>
         <city>São Paulo</city>
         <state>SP</state>
         <country>BRA</country>
       </address>
    </sender>
    <preApproval>
        <charge>auto</charge>
        <name>testes Ultimate</name>
            <details>
                Todos os dias 26 de cada mes
            </details>
        <amountPerPayment>19.90</amountPerPayment>
        <period>Monthly</period>
        <finalDate>2018-01-21T00:00:000-03:00</finalDate>
        <maxTotalAmount>2500.00</maxTotalAmount>
        <date>2016-08-25T20:33:00.sTZD</date>
    </preApproval> 

 </preApprovalRequest>
';




    $xml = str_replace("\n", '', $xml);
    $xml = str_replace("\r",'',$xml);
    $xml = str_replace("\t",'',$xml);

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1"));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $data = array('entrada' => $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
    $resposta = curl_exec($ch)or die(curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

        //echo $url;
        //exit;

    $retorno = simplexml_load_string($resposta);
    $xml    = json_encode($retorno);
    $array  = json_decode($xml,TRUE);


    print_r($array);
```

Está me retornando:

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [code] => 11101 [message] => preApproval data is required. ) )
```

O que há?

Comment: Você ta passando duas vezes as tags, já tentou removê-lás? 
 <receiver> e <reference> e <redirectURL> no final, sendo que no inicio, vc já setou elas.

Comment: Você está usando HTTPS ou HTTP? Há algum firewall no seu servidor?

Comment: Opa @GustavoTinoco removi as tags duplicadas, obrigado nem tinha visto.

Mas, ainda continua o erro no xml.

A conexão é HTTP

Comment: Não sei é isso. Mas eu lembro que é necessário cadastrar o redirecionamento na area de configuração do pagseguro https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/finalizacao-do-pagamento.html#v2-item-redirecionando-o-comprador-para-uma-url-fixa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi, segue código completo funcional para gerar assinatura via API com o Pagseguro:

```
$url = "https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/pre-approvals/request?email=email@hotmail.com&token=************************************";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
    <preApprovalRequest>
     <redirectURL>http://www.site.com.br/retorno.php</redirectURL>
     <reviewURL>http://www.site.com.br/revisao.php</reviewURL>
     <reference>REF1234</reference>
     <sender>
       <name>Nome do Cliente</name>
       <email>cliente@uol.com.br</email>
       <phone>
         <areaCode>82</areaCode>
         <number>99999999</number>
       </phone>
       <address>
       <street>Avenida Brigadeiro Faria Lima</street>
         <number>1384</number>
         <complement>1 Andar</complement>
         <district>Jardim Paulistano</district>
         <postalCode>01452002</postalCode>
         <city>São Paulo</city>
         <state>SP</state>
         <country>BRA</country>
       </address>
     </sender>
     <preApproval>
       <charge>auto</charge>
       <name>Seguro contra roubo do Notebook</name>
       <details>Todo dia 28 será cobrado o valor de R$100,00 referente ao seguro contra
                roubo de Notebook
        </details>
       <amountPerPayment>19.90</amountPerPayment>
       <period>Monthly</period>
       <finalDate>2018-01-21T00:00:000-03:00</finalDate>
       <maxTotalAmount>2000.00</maxTotalAmount>
       </preApproval>
     </preApprovalRequest>
';


$xml = str_replace("\n", '', $xml);
$xml = str_replace("\r",'',$xml);
$xml = str_replace("\t",'',$xml);


$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$xml= curl_exec($curl);


if($xml == 'Unauthorized'){
   // header('Location: paginaDeErro.php');
    echo 'Unauthorized';
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);

$xml_retorno= simplexml_load_string($xml);

if(count($xml_retorno -> error) > 0)
{
    print_r($xml_retorno -> error).'<br>';
    //header('Location: paginaDeErro.php');
    exit;
}

$xml    = json_encode($xml_retorno);
$array  = json_decode($xml,TRUE);
//print_r($array);

header('Location: https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/pre-approvals/request.html?code='.$array['code']);
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro `11101` refere-se ao `preApproval data is required` como consta na sua resposta de erro. Na tradução direta para o português de 'data is requered.' significa 'dados são requiridos' ou 'dados são necessários.' Pelo que percebo, você não preencheu todos os campos como requerido de acordo a documentação do [Guia de Integração do PagSeguro](http://download.uol.com.br/pagseguro/docs/pagseguro-assinatura-automatica.pdf).

URL do serviço de Assinatura do PagSeguro:

```
POST https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/pre-approvals/request
```

O cabeçalho `Content-Type` deve ser informado como no exemplo abaixo descrito na documentação:

```
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

> Observação: caso sua aplicação ou loja não utilize o conjunto de
>   caracteres ISO-8859-1, p.e.(UTF-8), é necessário substituir o
>   parâmetro charset do exemplo acima.

Veja abaixo exemplo de XML estruturado para representar os dados de um pagamento:

```
<preApprovalRequest>
 <redirectURL>http://www.seusite.com.br/retorno.php</redirectURL>
 <reviewURL>http://www.seusite.com.br/revisao.php</reviewURL>
 <reference>REF1234</reference>
 <sender>
   <name>Nome do Cliente</name>
   <email>cliente@uol.com.br</email>
   <phone>
     <areaCode>11</areaCode>
     <number>56273440</number>
   </phone>
   <address>
   <street>Avenida Brigadeiro Faria Lima</street>
     <number>1384</number>
     <complement>1 Andar</complement>
     <district>Jardim Paulistano</district>
     <postalCode>01452002</postalCode>
     <city>São Paulo</city>
     <state>SP</state>
     <country>BRA</country>
   </address>
 </sender>
 <preApproval>
   <charge>auto</charge>
   <name>Seguro contra roubo do Notebook</name>
   <details>Todo dia 28 será cobrado o valor de R$100,00 referente ao seguro contra
roubo de Notebook</details>
   <amountPerPayment>100.00</amountPerPayment>
   <period>Monthly</period>
   <finalDate>2014-01-21T00:00:000-03:00</finalDate>
   <maxTotalAmount>2400.00</maxTotalAmount>
   </preApproval>
 </preApprovalRequest>
```

#### Resposta do Servidor

Caso a chamada seja efetuada com sucesso, o PagSeguro retornará um `XML` com o código de redirecionamento. O exemplo abaixo mostra uma resposta de sucesso a uma chamada ao serviço deassinatura:

```
<preApprovalRequest>
  <code>DC2DAC98FBFBDD1554493F94E85FAE05</code>
  <date>2014-01-21T00:00:00.000-03:00</date>
</preApprovalRequest>
```

Caso a requisição retorne com erro:

```
<errors>
  <error>
    <code>11101</code>
    <message>preApproval data is required.</message>
  </error>
</errors>
```

> Um campo que merece destaque é o **`redirectURL`**, onde o mesmo SÓ
>   IRÁ FUNCIONAR SE NA SUA CONTA CONTA ESTIVER MARCADO “Quero receber
>   somente pagamentos via API”;

#### Detalhes

- [Guia de Integração](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/visao-geral.html)

**Boa Sorte!**

Comment: Bom dia amigão, verifiquei o xml que enviou, no meu estava faltando apenas o <address> e o <phone>, revi a url, alterei o cabeçalho, está tudo ok, mas, mesmo assim continuar o erro, vou editar o código do post para o código já alterado.

Comment: @sNniffer Você verificou também a questão do `Content-Type`? Se não estiver na configuração correta, não vai funcionar. Na documentação está explicito assim:para usar `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Sim, estou setando no cURL `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1"));
`

Comment: @sNniffer desculpa cara, eu errei ali mas já corrigi. A questão do `Content-type`, você está enviando usando `XML`., ai tem que ser `Content-Type: application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1`... tinha esquecido deste detalhes.

Comment: Putz amigão, mudei o content-type, e mudou o erro, recebo: `Array ( [error] => Array ( [code] => Malformed request XML: {0}. [message] => Malformed request XML: Content is not allowed in prolog.. ) )`, o que será que tem de errado no xml, não consegui identificar

Comment: @sNniffer como te disse, deixa o `Content-Type` com  `application/xml` mesmo. Pois você está enviando os parametros em formato `.xml`. Esse erro está dando porque o .xml está mal formatado.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44752/discussion-between-seamusd-and-snniffer).